# Incorrect Host IP after docker daemon run

Tags: docker, docker-machine

My host ip changes to the docker internal network ip i.e. 172.17.x.x after the docker daemon is run. Restarting the docker daemon resets the ip, temorarily, back to the original 192.168.x.x Any ideas on what the issue is and how to resolve. My Local network has an internal DNS server.

The host server is running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/)?

Comment: Yes I did review that page. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything to address the issue above.

Comment: Can you post your **ifconfig** on your question, or **ip address show**?